# Notation: units with negative exponents

Tags: notation, units, si-units, metrology

I'm not sure if this belongs on Meta or here but:

In many scientific journals, books, and posts on this site and others, I see the negative exponent convention used for units, e.g.

$\mathrm{N} \,\mathrm{kg}^{-2}\, \mathrm{m}^2$

$\mathrm{W \, m^{-2} \, K^{-1}}$

or even something as simple as

$\mathrm{m \, s^{-1}}$

To me personally, aesthetically speaking I suppose, this is somewhat of a detriment to readability compared to a slash notation

$\mathrm{N}\,\mathrm{m}^2/\mathrm{kg}^{2}\, $

$\mathrm{W/(m^{2} \, K)}$

$\mathrm{m/s}$

One of the main benefits is that it negates the need for -1 exponents simply to show the unit is in the denominator.  And it does not make the unit any less able to be written in linear type form. I cannot imagine the negative exponent form was easier to use in the typewriter and pre-digital publishing days, so it seems like a modern development?

If someone thought the parentheses are too busy looking,  I would even argue that

$\mathrm{W/m^{2} \, K}$

is unambiguous, since if Kelvin were in the numerator we would write

$\mathrm{W\,K/m^{2}}$

My question: I am assuming that some journals, publishers, and authors require or prefer the negative exponent form. Is there a reason for this, especially a technical one I am not seeing? Or is the choice purely stylistic preference?

Comment: For people with good understanding of negativ exponent it's  just no difference. It may be difficult for young students or complete laymen.

Comment: This definitely a question for the main site, not Meta.

Comment: The problem is that, while you and everybody else thinks that the meaning of $a/bc$ is obvious, people are split roughly evenly on whether it's obviously $a/(bc)$ or $(a/b)c$. Even in your example, for instance. The grouping $W/m^2$ is very natural, since it is an intensity, so $W/m^2 K$ reads as $(W/m^2) K$ to many.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mixed_division_and_multiplication): “In some of the academic literature, multiplication denoted by juxtaposition (also known as implied multiplication) is interpreted as having higher precedence than division. … The manuscript submission instructions for the Physical Review journals state that multiplication is of higher precedence than division, and this is also the convention observed in prominent physics textbooks such as the Course of Theoretical Physics by Landau and Lifshitz and the Feynman Lectures on Physics.”

Comment: It's a good point about $W/m^2K$ and the potential ambiguity.  But even then in my opinion writing $W/(m^2K)$, or in general $a^nb^mc^l/(d^pe^qf^r)$ with parentheses is easier to read and take in at a glance than the negative exponent way. My main inquiry is whether there is a strong technical reason to prefer the negative exponent form

Answer (score 4):

> RC_23 asked: *"I am assuming that some journals, publishers, and authors require or prefer..."*

I've seen different notations in the same journal, but you have to keep it consistent within the paper. In some papers they even ignore Pemdas and write $\rm a^2/b^3 c^4$ if they mean $\rm a^2/(b^3 c^4)=a^2/b^3/c^4$, so you always have to check the units if in doubt. If you use the positive and negative exponents on the other hand there is no disambiguity like that in $\rm a^2 \ b^{-3} c^{-4}$.

Comment: *In some papers…* I’ve never seen a physics paper in which $a^2/b^2c^2$ **didn’t** mean $a^2/(b^2c^2)$.

Comment: @Ghoster - sure, because otherwise you would bring all the multiplications to the left and write a²c²/b² instead, but according to Pemdas a²/b²c² would be just that, so if in doubt you always have to use your brain since for some things there are no rules, only conventions.

Comment: The superscript negative signs don't render for me which is why I changed it. They just look like boxes. Not a big deal but FYI

Comment: @RC_23 - I reverted it because you only changed one equation to Latex and left all the other ones untouched, which looked like crap. You also got the exponent for a negative although it should be positive, but if the Unicode doesn't render for you I'll change it to Latex in a minute.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn’t really matter too much, since it’s just a notational convention.

But in some cases you can have fractional or even irrational exponents on the units, in which case the slash notation is less advantageous.

Also, from a theoretical perspective, using negative powers makes it clear that any possible unit is a product of powers of some fixed based units, and it makes it slightly easier to figure out the unit for products or quotients of quantities (you just add or subtract the exponents for each base unit).

Comment: I'd be interested to see an example of a physical law involving an irrational exponent.  Or do you mean e.g. in a power fit?

Comment: @RC_23 In statistical physics, [critical exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_exponent) near phase transitions are typically irrational, and so the coefficients must have irrational dimension. I don't know if you'd call that a "physical law", since the critical exponents depend on the Hamiltonian's universality class, but they are universal (in the technical sense of the term) and can be derived theoretically; they aren't just fits to empirical data.

Comment: Interesting!.......